# Bootstrap nav menu being hidden by sidebar when block added

Tags: html, css, wordpress, twitter-bootstrap

When I add in an additional html block into my sidebar it seems to float  over my nav which obstructs a couple of the links from working.

E.G. on https://www.moneynest.co.uk/pension-crisis-uk/ the about and contact us links being obstructed.

[image]

Yet when I don't have the additional sidebar block (the yellow ad) e.g. on: https://www.moneynest.co.uk/stock-market-crash/ the issue does not occur.

I've tried adding:

```
section#text-9 {
    margin-top: 40px!important;
}
```

Into my stylesheet but it doesn't seem to be picking it up.

Any ideas what's going on?

Thanks,

Sam

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Managed to figure this one out, it was due to an odd  being present in my blog post content.

Answer (score 0):

Kindly be more specific what is floating over the nav?
I would appreciate it if you shared and img

Comment: Thanks, have just added an image above.